# linking a map to a file with scala, to run a text based game

Tags: arrays, scala, mapping, case-class

I'm taking a beginning programming class, and we're on to making text based games, more like read you're own adventures then actual games and I don't quite understand how to get the information form my map, which has all the room information, into a file that will run it.
I have the rooms file set up like...

```
0 roomone
you enter a room, and it looks odd. you can go north or south. which way?
2
north 1
south 2
//will having a space here make a difference? should i delete these?
1 hall
theres a hall here, with a door running east. continue north,go east, or go back south?
3
north 3
south 0
east 4
```

and so on, so that the room is assigned a number and a name, then it gets a description, then list the number of exits, list what they are,  and then list which numbered room that answer should take you to. I don't know how to get it so that it reads into two things, one that takes the first three bits of information as room information, and the second which reads into the number of exits and creates an array with that number of exits, and then reads in the exits, and thier numbers.

what i have is

```
case class Map(location:Int,place:String,description:String,exits:Array )

case class Exits(numberexits:Int,direction:String,destination:Int)
```

I know there's probably some easy answer, but I'm really pretty lost on what I should be doing. I don't know how to get my file read in so the right parts go to the right places, and I'm enough of a beginner that alot of what i've been reading isn't very clear to me, so hopefully my questions clear enough that someone can help me out, and tell if i'm going about this even sort of right, and if it will work when i actually try to put it together, since if i understand what i'm doing it has to take user input, look up the direction typed in from the array of exits, look at the destination associated with that, then take that destination and look for a location in map that has that number and take you there and then println(Map.description) and wait for the next input?

Answer (score 4):

It seems every other question these days I see parser combinators.

```
case class Exit(direction:String,destination:Int)
case class Map(location:Int, place:String, description:String, exits:List[Exit] )

object ReadConf extends scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers {
  override protected val whiteSpace = " +".r
  def eol = "\n"
  def number = "\\d+".r ^^ (_.toInt)

  // Overall format
  def conf = (comment.* ~> map).*
  def map = header ~ description ~ exits ^^ {
    case location ~ place ~ description ~ exits => 
      Map(location, place, description, exits)
  }
  def comment = "//.*".r ~ eol

  // Map parts (except exits)
  def header = location ~ place <~ eol
  def description = ".*".r <~ eol
  def location = number
  def place = "\\w+".r

  // Exits
  def exits = numberOfExits <~ eol >> nExits
  def nExits(n: Int) = repN(n, exit)
  def exit = direction ~ destination <~ eol ^^ {
    case direction ~ destination => Exit(direction, destination)
  }
  def numberOfExits = number
  def direction = "\\w+".r
  def destination = number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the file in with `val lines = scala.io.source.fromFile.getLines().toList` or somesuch.

Don't call anything `Map`, since Scala already has a `Map` which you may want to use.

Now that you have all the lines, you can figure out how to parse them.  You may want to use matching:

```
lines match {
  case a :: b :: c :: remainder =>
    // Execute this code if and only if there are at least 3 lines in the list;
    // if so, pull the first 3 out and call them a, b, and c
  case _ =>
    // Otherwise execute this
 }
```

And you may also wish to use recursion (this would just break the thing up into a list of rooms, but it wouldn't extract the information from each room):

```
def parse(lines: List[String], roomsText: List[List[String]] = Nil): List[List[String]] = {
  lines match {
    case Nil => rooms    // Parsed all the lines, so return what we've already found
    case /* whatever conditions you need */ =>
      // do stuff to find one more room
      parse(remainingLines, newRoom :: roomsText)
  }
}
```

Once you do more parsing (`.split(" ")` on strings may be helpful) and get everything into the case class, which I will call `Room` instead of `Map`, you take user input (see `Console`), convert it to an integer (try `.toInt`), and look it up in your list of rooms.  For that, a real map might be useful:

```
val roomsByNumber = rooms.map(room => (room.location, room)).toMap
```

Now `roomsByNumber(n)` will look up the `n`'th room.

Hopefully this will help you get started.  Good luck!

P.S. I have no idea what you've already been taught, so I can't tell if what I'm writing makes sense or looks like gibberish; most classes expect you to use mostly what you've already been taught, so you should see what you can manage given what you've already learned over trying to adopt any strategy I've suggested here.  But don't name the room case class `Map` unless explicitly told to--that's just asking for trouble using the built-in `Map`.